# dispersion of point on gnuplot with 3 columns

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file with 2 columns, time and score. I want to add the third column that will show how much the score decreased at the same time. For example

```
10, 200, 180
11, 210, 200
```

Gnuplot should show a line linking these two points.
At the moment my gnuplot script only show points dispersions for 2 columns.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set grid
set title 'Reputação dos peers quando excluíram arquivos'
set xlabel 'Tempo Discreto da exclusão'
set ylabel 'Reputação'

set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 1 pi -1 ps 1.0
set style line 2 lc rgb '#dd181f' lt 1 lw 1 pi -1 ps 1.0
set pointintervalbox 0
plot 'ReputationOnExclusion.txt' using 1:2 with points ls 1 title 'Exclusão'
pause -1
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to achieve. Should the point `10,200` connected with `10,180`? Or how should the third column be interpreted?

Comment: yes, like a standard deviation, but only to under of the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect the `y`-value in the second column with the value in the third column, you can use the `vectors` plotting style:

```
set style line 1 lc rgb '#00f0ad' lt 1
set style arrow 1 linestyle 1 nohead
plot 'ReputationOnExclusion.txt' using 1:2:(0):($3-$2) with vectors arrowstyle 1
```

The values in the `using` statement are `x y xdelta ydelta`. `xdelta` is `0`, `ydelta` is the difference between the third and second column (is a relative value).